# lis = [1,2,3,4,5] x = input('Введи эл, котор нуж искл:') lis.remove(x) print(lis) - если х зад в прог то раб, если ввод через input не работ

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
lis = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = 4
lis.remove(x)
print(lis)
х = input('Введи элемент, который нужно исключить:') 
lis.remove(x)
print(lis)
```

если значение х задаю в программе то работает, если x вводить через `input` -  не работает

Comment: input возвращает строку - преобразуйте в число

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = 4
lis.remove(x)
print(lis)
х = int(input('Введи элемент, который нужно исключить:'))
lis.remove(x)
print(lis)
```

`x` необходимо преобразовать в тип `int`